# Discuss the continuity, differentiability, integrability of the function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

Discuss the continuity, differentiability, integrability of the function
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} x^2,x\in \mathbb{Q} \\ 0,  x\in \mathbb{R/Q}\end{cases}$$
Is the function discontinuous at everywhere? I got this by discussing if the point is rational or irrational. And construct a rational sequence converges to irrational point , an irrational sequence to rational point.
Now if the function is discontinuous then we can easily conclude  it is not differentiable.
And I don't know how to discuss the integrability of the function.

Comment: Integrability: Lebesgue criterion, or by definition consider the sup and inf on subintervals. If consider the integral on the whole line, then additionally the limit should be also considered.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**

- The function is continuous at $0$ because $|f(x)|\le x^2.$
- The function is differentiable at $0$ because the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$ exits.
- Assuming you are asking about Riemann integrability: What can you say about the set about the set of points of discontinuity? Does it have any relation with being integrable?

Comment: It is discontinuous at everywhere except $x=0$, Sorry I still don't get the point how to make it to integrability. I was always wondering do it by definition or Darboux sum.

Comment: There is a result that says the following: "A bounded function $f : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable if and only if
$\{x | f$ is not continuous at $x\}$ has measure zero." Can you use it?

Comment: @JaqenChou If consider the Darboux theorem, then on any closed interval which does not contain $0$ the oscillation would be greater than some $x^2$, which gives non-integrability.